# How to close a popup window in a parent window?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to close a popup window which has been loaded by a parent window.

This popup window is a `Documentviewer` window in my webapp.

I need to close this viewer by clicking a logout button which is in master page.

My code:

```
public string MySession //server side code

{
    get 
    {
        if (Session["RegID"] != null)
        {
            return Session["RegID"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

}


//client side code
   $(window).load(function() {

      Start();
   });


    function Start()
    {
      timedCount();
      var t=setTimeout("Start()",10000);
    }


   function timedCount()
   { 
     /*var out="<%=Session["RegID"]%>";*/


      var out='<%=MySession%>'; 
      if(out!="")
      {
        alert(out);       
      }else
      {
        window.close();
      }

   }
```

Server code is executed at very first time only.

My target is to close the popup if it is opened when user logs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have something like this on your parent page:

```
window.open(...);
```

If you change this to:

```
var popup = window.open(...);
```

then at any time you can close it by coding:

```
popup.close();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/bjkNx/1/

Comment: lnkbtnView.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:window.open('demo.aspx?upkey=1&ProdName=aaa')"              lnbtnView is a Linkbutton exist in a Gridview ....show i cant maintain a variable popup as you said...

Answer (score 0):

Put your popup window in global variable:

```
<script>
    var popupWindow;

    function openw(url) {
        popupWindow = window.open(url, "popup", "");
    }

    function closew() {
        if (popupWindow) {
            popupWindow.close();
        }
    }

</script>
<a href="javascript:openw('about:blank')">open</a><br />
<a href="javascript:closew()">close</a>
```