# How to make previous page refresh after I click a button in pop-up window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, popupwindow, cross-page-posting

My main page has a `GridView` and `Button`s for add/update. When I click the update button, a window pops up(used `JavaScript`) which has input fields and a `Button` for actually updating the record. What I want to know is how to refresh the main page when I click the update button inside the pop-up window.

This is the partial code of what I tried on actual update's `OnClick`:

```
if (PreviousPage != null)
            {
                GridView gridv = (GridView)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
                gridv.DataBind();
            }
```

While debugging, I realized that the if statement was never executed. Does that mean pop-up windows do not have a `PreviousPage` initially? If so how can I reach the **Main** page then? *(i shall note that the main page is not a master page)*

This is how I create the pop-up on button click from the Main page(so it's a new window):

```
function btnEditEP_Click() {
            var recID = document.getElementById('<%=tboxEdit.ClientID%>').value;
            window.open("editPopupEP.aspx?Txt=" + recID, "_blank", "toolbar=yes", "resizable=yes", "scrollbars=yes");
        }
```

Comment: Is it not possible at all? Anyone?

Comment: What kind of Pop up are you using? If you are on same page you can easily bind your Gridview again.

Comment: @Ali Umair See the edited question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your child window you can call a function something like this in your child window call on your update function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunction() {

            window.opener.PostBackParentWindow();
            window.close();
        }
  </script>
```

and in your parent window call add this code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function PostBackParentWindow() {

            __doPostBack(null, null);
        }
</script>
```

Hope it might help

Answer (score 0):

On the update click also perform the close pop up call

```
<script>
var popupWindow;

function openw(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url, "popup", "");
}

function closew() {
    if (popupWindow) {
        popupWindow.close();
    }
}

</script>
<a href="javascript:openw('about:blank')">open</a><br />
<a href="javascript:closew()">close</a>
```

like described here . [How to close a popup window in a parent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899016/how-to-close-a-popup-window-in-a-parent-window)

and then in `closw` you can call your parent page with true/false value depending on your update operation. You can use a `hiddenfield` for this.